# Feof в Си зациклилось

Tags: c

Задача состоит в том, чтобы переписать бинарный файл значениями в квадрате.

```
int a, n;
FILE * f = fopen("name.dat","rb+");
fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, f);
while(!feof(f)) {
a = a*a;
n = sizeof(a);
fseek(f, -n, SEEK_CUR);
fwrite(&a, sizeof(a), 1, f);
fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, f);
}
fclose(f);
```

зациклилось while. данные принимает до бесконечности. плюс когда принудительно закрываю программу и читаю файл, то выясняется, что данные туда не записались. В чем проблема никак не могу понять.

Comment: В Linux-е это работает. 

`fflush()` и даже `fclose()` тут вообще ни при чем.

--

А вот в винде (Win 7, gcc 3.4.5) у меня тоже зацикливается, причем файл постоянно растет (до Cntr-C программе).

--

Видимо там проще всего решить задачу, используя 2 файла

      fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, f);
      FILE *g = fopen("name.dat", "rb+");
      fseek(g, 0, SEEK_SET);
      while(!feof(f)) {
        a = a*a;
        n = sizeof(a);
    //    fseek(f, -n, SEEK_CUR);
        fwrite(&a, sizeof(a), 1, g);
        fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, f);
      }

Также ждем ответов от знатоков винды.

Comment: @avp, задача решена без использования дополнительного файла. Нужно просто между вызовами fwrite() и fread() использовать fflush(), а также проверять fread() количество байтов, которых она прочитала. Если они != sizeof(a), значит выход.

Comment: Отлично. Только, конечно, для такой записи 

        fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, f)

проверять надо не sizeof, а на 1. 

Кстати, посмотрел и обнаружил, что независимо от fflush() в винде feof() в такой программе с fseek() не работает. 

Поэтому получаем 

    int main () {
      int a;
      FILE *f = fopen("name.dat","rb+");
    
      while(fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, f) == 1) {
        a *= a;
        fseek(f, -sizeof(a), SEEK_CUR);
        fwrite(&a, sizeof(a), 1, f);
        fflush(f);
      }
    
      return fclose(f) == EOF;
    }

вот такой код.

Answer (score 1):

что бы данные записывались их надо сбрасывать методом **flush()** , который вызывается при закрытии файла. И естественно у вас зацикливание произойдет. Вы же читаете и одновременно записываете! Что такое конец файла? Это символ, а его вы никогда не достигнете!

Comment: ok. как же тогда перезаписать файл, если не можно одновременно использовать fread и fwrite?

Comment: стандартная техника перезаписи:
1)создать файл и назвать buffer
2)записывать в buffer все что хотите видеть в своем исходном файле
3)удалить исходный файл и переименовать buffer

Comment: но, например, если мне нужно будет изменить часть файла, тогда "стандартная техника перезаписи" не очень продуктивная.
Плюс. Зачем тогда существует метод открытия файла, как rb+ (открыть для чтения и записи в бинарном режиме)?

Comment: @voipp, Вы серьезно предлагаете таким способом менять гигабайтные файлы?